Devextreme TreeList validation is not working while datasource loading
<dxi-validation-rule
  type="custom"
  [validationCallback]="validateUniqueCode"
  message="{{ 'Duplicate code'}}"
  [reevaluate]="true"
></dxi-validation-rule>

I am putting validation on treelist in devextreme angular. It working fine only when i add new row or edit any existing row. Its not validating data while loading to treelist from datasource initially. I want to validate sourcedata also. How can I achieve it?
